# Состыковка картинки и кнопки в адаптивном дизайне

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.Вопрос такой.Есть картинка и нужно в определенном месте расположить кнопку.Как это сделать при адаптивной верстке?Как я это вижу,то позиционирование и обычные штучки не помогут тк картинка сжимается по-другому нежели кнопка.Пример [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как синюю кнопку прицепить к тому месту?Заранее благодарен

Comment: А что вы пробовали? Где пример нерабочего кода?

Comment: Ответил кодом ниже

Answer (score 1):

Перед этим идет похожий блок на весь экран

```css
    .button {
    height: 5%;
    border-radius: 20px; 
    background-color:#19A4EC;
    position: absolute;  
    }
    .registration1 {
    left:42%;
    top: 70%;
    }
    .button-parent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    } 

    .registration2 {
    height: 7%;
    left:25%;
    top: 303%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="second-block">
    <div style="width:100%">
    <div class="button-parent">
    <button class="button registration2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <a href="" >Зарегистрироваться</a>
    </button>   
    </div>
    <img src="style/2-3.jpg" class="img-responsive"  >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Перед этим идет блок на весь экран.Поэтому кнопка позиционируется сверху аж на 300% и при адаптиве сьезжает